# Query with unique int results

Tags: sql, distinct

I'm trying to figure out how to resolve this query, might be very simple but I can't understand how to do it so far.
What I want to do is to sum up companies by their entity (1, which never changes of value) and group them by categories. The thing is that these companies have buckets, and when I do this the query also sums up all the buckets, which I do not seek. Between these period I'm getting 10 companies as result, when I should be getting 6, two of them have more than one bucket.
I only wish to sum or count 1 bucket per company.

```
`SELECT DISTINCT c.label AS category, COUNT(s.entity) AS company
FROM llx_categorie c
INNER JOIN llx_categorie_societe cs ON c.rowid = cs.fk_categorie
INNER JOIN llx_societe s ON cs.fk_soc = s.rowid
INNER JOIN llx_propal p ON s.rowid = p.fk_soc
WHERE p.datec BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-01-31'
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY category ASC`
```

If I need to clarify anything else I'll do it, thanks in advance!

Comment: Please 1. tag the sql dialect that you are using and 2. provide sample dataset and expected output

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT s.entity)` is supported by most DBMSes.

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer.